# Custom asset is not visible in Asset Publisher portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

My custom asset is not visible in `Asset Publisher`. I created portlets and service layer according to [this](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/generating-your-service-layer-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-04-en) guide. so I have `Location` model. After create or update `location` I update entry:

```
public void addLocation(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        Location location = _updateLocation(request);
        User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);
            AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(user.getUserId(),
                PortalUtil.getScopeGroupId(request), Location.class.getName(),
                location.getLocationId(), new long[0], new String[] { "mycat1",
                        "mucat2" });
        sendRedirect(request, response);
    }
```

AssetEntry is stored in database:

```
SELECT entryid, groupid, companyid, userid, username, createdate, modifieddate, 
       classnameid, classpk, classuuid, classtypeid, visible, startdate, 
       enddate, publishdate, expirationdate, mimetype, title, description, 
       summary, url, layoutuuid, height, width, priority, viewcount
  FROM assetentry order by createdate desc limit 1;
```

Result:

left side of result
[image: left side of result]
right side of result
[image: right side of result]

Why Asset Publisher not show my asset if asset exists in database?
Maybe I should specify some layout because Asset Publisher don't know how to show my asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To utilize Asset Framework properly, you need to do few more things. First of all Asset Publisher needs to know how to access your objects metadata - you have to provide custom `AssetRendererFactory` / `AssetRenderer` classes and a JSP file which will render your entity.

Read more in https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/asset-framework-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-06-en under the section **Publishing Assets with Asset Publisher**.

Comment: I thought that `publishing asset` means adding new asset to portal (I do it in my code). I made mistake in translation. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :) One more thing, remember to put all you data-related business logic (for example adding assets) to service implementations, not actions of your portlet (as it is now in your quersion). Check how it is done at Liferay's knowledgebase - https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/portlets/knowledge-base-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/liferay/knowledgebase/service/impl/KBArticleLocalServiceImpl.java#L131-L213.